Line integrals of vector fields other than force
Does a line integral of a vector field have any physical meaning if its function isn't a force? For instance, if I compute a line integral of an acceleration function, will this integral have work per mass dimension?

There are many examples where the line integral of a vector field which is not a force has a physical meaning. One of the best examples is found in Ampere's law, where the magnetic field is (line)-integrated to the current $j$ inside the loop of the line contour:
$$\int d\mathbf{s} \cdot \mathbf{H} = j$$
Note that $\mathbf{H}$ is not a force, the force on a charged particle in a magnetic field is given by the Lorentz force relation, in  particular the Lorentz force is not scalar-proportional to the magnetic field $\mathbf{H}$.
If the acceleration (instead of the force) is line-integrated, indeed one gets a quantity whose dimensions is work/mass. The dimensional analysis includes integrals. If the integration variable has a certain dimension it multiplies with the dimension of the integrand.
In case of Ampere's law $\mathbf{H}$ has the dimension of $A/m$ which multiplies with the dimension of the integration variable $\mathbf{s}$ to give $A$, the dimension of the current $j$.
EDIT:
Actually, one can even integrate an accelerating force along a circular line, of course the  force cannot be associated with a conservative potential.
A betatron (an example for an accelerator)  is based on Faraday's law($S$ is the surface the magnetic field is covering, and $\partial S$ its border):
$$\oint_{\partial S} \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_S \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{A}$$
Electrons can be accelerated within a ramping (increasing) magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$. The changing the magnetic field creates an electric field $\mathbf{E}$ on the border of an area which the magnetic field covers. The electrons will feel the electric field that is created and are accelerated along the electric fields lines which are closed. After made one turn they make another one and so on. Of course the magnetic field cannot be ramped forever for technical reasons. So the process won't go on forever.

Whether something has 'physical meaning' is a matter of perspective, but line integrals of vector fields that aren't forces do show up in physics. An example is electrodynamics, where the electrostatic potential difference is:
$$\Delta V=-\int_C \textbf{E}\cdot d\textbf{l}$$
Obviously, the electric field is closely related to the force, as the force due to an electric field is $\textbf{F}=q\textbf{E}$. Another example is the magnetic flux through some surface, which can be written as a line integral of the magnetic vector potential:
$$\Phi=\iint_S \textbf{B}\cdot d\textbf{S}=\iint_S\left(\nabla\times\textbf{A} \right)\cdot d\textbf{S}=\oint_{\partial S}\textbf{A}\cdot d\textbf{l}  $$

Thank you, your explanation is very useful

If you find either of the two answers satisfying I recommend you accept one of them. If not, consider leaving a comment about what's still unclear to you.
